# docker login self hosted registry = x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, ssl

I am new to docker and trying to setup my registry for docker swarm.

I have three debian installations interacting with each other:

- registry
- website
- database

Trying to setup my database separate from my website and my registry separate too.

My `registry machine` also hosts a website let say `vmreg.com` managed by `letsencrypt` ssl certificates. I use this certificate to sign both my website and registry.

`docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -v` $(pwd)`/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com:/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com/domain.key -p 5000:5000 registry:2`

On my database machine I can login just fine:
`echo "password" | docker login -u username --password-stdin  vmreg.com:5000`

but on my `website machine` I get `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` when I try to login

Only difference is that my `website machine` also has its own `letsencrypt` domain setup. I don't understand why I get this error. Is it a possible conflict ?

Solutions I found online all talk about copying certificates but 1) I have not copied any cert on my `database machine` and 2) I don't understand why I would need to copy certificates from the registry server to a client; that makes no sense to me because what happens when I renew my certs

Comment: What's the Linux distribution and version of the failing host, and can you provide the version of the ca-certificates package?

Comment: on the registry or the website ? What command shoud I run for those infos ?

Comment: On the website host. Every Linux distribution will be different. E.g. on Debian, `cat /etc/debian_version` and `dpkg -l 'ca-certificates'`.

Comment: debian is 10.12 but `dpkg -l 'ca-certificates'` gives `dpkg-query: no packages found matching ca-certificates`

Answer (score 2):

> but on my website machine I get x509: certificate signed by unknown authority when I try to login

I always had to follow "[Verify repository client with certificates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/)" when establishing a new Docker registry (usually one based on [Nexus3](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/docker-registry) for instance).

That means:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d$ mkdir vmreg.com
/etc/docker/certs.d$ cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com/domain.crt vmreg.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the latest certificate bundle, and LetsEncrypt had to update their root CA after their [original provider's certificate expired](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/). This is normally handled on Debian by running:

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

However, if that doesn't solve it, it may be because of older versions of Debian. See [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/q/1079199/351549) that describes how to solve it.

Comment: tried but no result.